# Printing out each row from a MYSQL table individually in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to individually print out each line from my SQL database in PHP. I am trying to do this so each line that is retrieved, it can act like a link which will direct the user to another page. For example, the current SQL query will output the Category names from the database Category, i would like it to output all the values from that table but have it so each one has a different redirect link to another page which clicked on.

```
$query = "SELECT CATEGORY_NAME
FROM CATEGORIES ORDER BY CATEGORY_ID ASC";      
$results = @mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);
if ($results) {
    if ($numrows >0) {
        echo '      
<table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>Categories</stong></td>

    </tr>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr>      
            <td>' . $row['CATEGORY_NAME'] . '</td>
            </tr> 
        '; 
        }
        mysqli_free_result ($results);
```

Such as,

```
Category 
__________

PS4
XBOX
```

i can click on PS4 and it would take me to another page, i know how to do this with a href and then print out the row in sql however, i'm not sure how do print out each row individually without printing them out using $row['CATEGORY_NAME'].

Thank you for any help

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: Explain....because what you're doing is exactly how you print each individually..

Comment: This isn't directly getting at an answer, but I highly recommend reading up on [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Code like you have above is vulnerable. E.g. what happens when someone puts a `CATEGORY_NAME` in the database called `<script src="myhackingwebsite.com/malicious_script.js"></script>PS3`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like? (I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question)

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>      
    <td><a href="somelink.php?cat=' . $row['CATEGORY_NAME'] . '">'  . 
    $row['CATEGORY_NAME'] . '</a></td>
    </tr> '; 
}
```

**UPDATE**
If a category is named playstation, playstation.php would be linked to...

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>      
    <td><a href="' . $row['CATEGORY_NAME'] . '.php">'  . 
    $row['CATEGORY_NAME'] . '</a></td>
    </tr> '; 
}
```

Though above would work a wild guess is that you're looking for something completely different. The thing you are looking for is essentially a way to present information for playstation, a way to present information about PS4 etc depending on what user clicks on!? In that case you should do something like this instead:

```
//Include ID of category in your sql-statement
$query = "SELECT ID, CATEGORY_NAME
FROM CATEGORIES ORDER BY CATEGORY_ID ASC"; 
....
....
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>      
    <td><a href="presentinfo.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">'  .  
    $row['CATEGORY_NAME'] . '</a></td>
    </tr> '; 
}
```

and create `presentinfo.php` file where you fetch information about the category, based on the id given in the url. (e.g.`select from categories id={id given in url}`)

Comment: I have 4 categories in the SQL table, i'm trying to have it so each entry has a different url which when clicked, redirects the user to. For example, they click on playstation, the user is redirected to playstation.php. If they click on xbox, they are redirected to xbox.php. I'm unsure of how i can retrieve the data from the database separately so i can assign a redirect to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the link to which it needs to be redirected in a new column `CATEGORY_URL` along with the `CATEGORY_NAME` and then print it out like so:

```
$query = "SELECT CATEGORY_NAME, CATEGORY_URL FROM CATEGORIES ORDER BY CATEGORY_ID ASC";      
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($results);
if ($numrows > 0) {
        echo '      
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Categories</stong></td>
        </tr>';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '
            <tr>      
              <td>
                <a href="'.$row['CATEGORY_URL'].'">'.$row['CATEGORY_NAME'].'</a>
              </td>
            </tr>'; 
        }
        mysqli_free_result ($results); 
} else {

// no results found 

}
```

OR if you just want to pass it as a url parameter, you just need to modify if like so:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/#q='.$row['CATEGORY_NAME'].'">'.$row['CATEGORY_NAME'].'</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="https://www.yoursite.com/'.$row['CATEGORY_NAME'].'.php">'.$row['CATEGORY_NAME'].'</a>
```